# TCP listener data type conversion

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I'm developing one TCP server application with TCP listener class. here my server application getting data on every second from client.

Client sending data in a predefined format. received data contains 15 messages separated by "\0". e.g "12\012345\012.12\0" and so on. after getting data i split data and convert it in to string array. so i have string array of 15 elements. after that each element get converted to specific data type and whole record goes in to database.

here data send/receive happens on every second. the problem i'm facing is my application not sending data on every second to client application.

when i remove data type conversion code all is working well as expected. but with conversion code its took more milliseconds and my application not able to send data back to client in time.

below is my code. if i remove data type conversion code from "MapVariables" function its working well.

Please please can any one help me on this?

```
private async void ProcessClient(TcpClient tcpClient, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, amountRead);

                string[] dataFromClient = Code.Common.SplitByLength(message, messageSize).ToArray();
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Select(x => ParseMessage(x)).ToArray();

                common.MapVariables(dataFromClient);

                string serverResponse = string.Join(", ", dataFromClient);
                //Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                await stream.WriteAsync(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length, ct);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            //loge exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //loge exception
        }
    }

public void MapVariables(string[] variables)
    {
        Variables.Variable1 = int.Parse(variables[0]);
        Variables.Variable2 = int.Parse(variables[1]);
        Variables.Variable3 = int.Parse(variables[2]);
        Variables.Variable4 = int.Parse(variables[3]);
        Variables.Variable5 = int.Parse(variables[4]);
        Variables.Variable6 = int.Parse(variables[5]);
        Variables.Variable7 = int.Parse(variables[6]);
        Variables.Variable8 = decimal.Parse(variables[7]);
        Variables.Variable9 = decimal.Parse(variables[8]);
        Variables.Variable10 = decimal.Parse(variables[9]);
        Variables.Variable11 = decimal.Parse(variables[10]);
        Variables.Variable12 = int.Parse(variables[11]);
        Variables.Variable13 = int.Parse(variables[12]);
        Variables.Variable14 = decimal.Parse(variables[13]);
        Variables.Variable15 = decimal.Parse(variables[14]);

        InsertintoDatabase();
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting exceptions? Are you sure your problem is not in `InsertintoDatabase` ?

Comment: What do you mean "not finish in time", what exactly is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: No Im not getting any exception but my application is not respond to client request within a second. each request/reply has to be complete in one second. when i remove data type conversion code and just insert default values to database its perform very well but when i include data type conversion code its getting 2 second sometimes and my communication get disturbed. i dont know but if there is any other better way of doing this please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, you just send back what they sent you except comma delimited.

You could move your `MapVariables(...)` call into a separate thread and use that. My guess is that your `InsertintoDatabase` call is the true bottleneck.

You could also attempt to just move `MapVariables(...)` to be done after you reply since it doesn't look like it will affect anything by doing it afterwards.

Comment: I will try it again by moving call to MapVariables(...) into different thread. InsertintoDatabase is not a real bottle neck because i already investigate on it and its not causing any issue.